# After migrating from SwiftUI to UIKit App Delegate Life Cycle, why am I getting a black screen on first launch?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uikit

Due to factors outside of my control, I need to migrate my app from SwiftUI to UIKit App Delegate lifecycle.

I've added an AppDelegate, Scene Delegate, and updated the info.plist.

After the conversion, the app starts up fine when installed for the first time.

The problem is when I install as an update from a previous version of the app that uses the SwiftUI life, I get a  black screen. If I then restart the app after getting the black screen, it works fine thereafter.

The app is already live in the App Store, so I need to release as an update and do not want users to get a black screen and have to restart the app.

I installed Xcode's sample 'Hello, World' app and did the same migration and am having the same black screen issue. Same issue from a TestFlight build.

When stepping though with the debugger, willConnectTo in the SceneDelegate is never executed.

Any ideas of how to fix or troubleshoot this?

Comment: Why are you switching in the first place? You can put an app delegate with SwiftUI lifecycle with about 8 lines of code and a SceneDelegate is unnecessary.

Comment: I have experienced that the sceneDelegate functions are not called. You can setup a AppDelegate as @loremipsum said, but I also remember that not all functions are called correctly. Probably still a problem, I suggest to setup the project from scratch. Making these drastic changes to the environment only cause problems as I can tell you, setting up a new project is much faster then debugging..

Comment: @loremipsum I originally did try to add an AppDelege to the SwiftUI lifecycle, but could not get remote notifications to work correctly.

Comment: @Felix Would you mind clarifying what you mean by setting up the project from scratch? I created a new project using the super simple sample app that's created with a new Xcode SwiftUI app. I migrated that to a UIKit lifecycle and had the same black screen problem.

Comment: You shouldn’t need the scene delegate, I would work in troubleshooting the remote notifications.

Comment: @zooBetty I would always recommend to create a project with AppDelegate lifecycle unless you have a super simple app idea. But for everything else, like your pushNotifications, the AppDelegate lifecycle is so important, so everything works. I went through that too, and I ended up in creating new apps always with AppDelegate. It's actually pretty easy to show SwiftUI views in a UIViewController. Sorry I can't give you a solution here, I spend hours on this as well.